# How to auto grow the kendo rich textbox without scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs-directive, kendo-ui

How would I auto grow the kendo Rich textarea without scrolling?.

How to automatically increase the height of the rich textarea.
I tried using `height: auto` in css but didn't got anything out of it

Comment: we cannot help you without code which you have tried before.please update your post

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/g0re3eFbEfu1JDSqvWBx?p=preview                                           @JayZamsol